# WordPress шорткод как выбирать и выводить из array?

Tags: wordpress, шорткод, shortcode

Такая проблема, хочу сделать шорткод на сайте. Не понимаю, как вывести текст. Ниже пример:

```
    function wpr_snap( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'q1' => 'Первый вариант',
        'q2' => 'Второй вариант',
        'q3' => 'Третий вариант',

    ), $atts));
    $img = '<div>'.$a['q1'].'</div>';
    return $img;
    } 
add_shortcode('hrs', 'wpr_snap');
```

Если коротко, хочу получить примерно такой результат:

`[hrs q1]` ---> `Первый вариант`

Но не понимаю, как это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры в шорткоде задаются так:

```
[hrs q="0"]
```

Ниже `shortcode_atts()` извлекает значение параметра q (по умолчанию - пустая строка). Дальше эта переданная строка преобразуется в целое и выводится соответствующий элемент массива.

```
function wpr_snap( $atts ) {
    $atts     = shortcode_atts( array( 'q' => '' ), $atts );
    $variants = array(
        'Первый вариант',
        'Второй вариант',
        'Третий вариант',
    );
    $img      = '<div>' . $variants( (int) $atts['q'] ) . '</div>';

    return $img;
}

add_shortcode( 'hrs', 'wpr_snap' );
```

Функцию extract использовать не нужно, она небезопасна и не рекомендуется к использованию стандартами WordPress.

Comment: Добавил, в итоге сайт что то перестал запускаться) Если что у  меня стоит плагин элементор